# React App showing blank page after deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

my react app works fine on my pc using google chrome (where I build it) but doesn't work on Microsoft edge, and also works fine in localhost, but on my laptop and phone it shows a blank page, my host is: http://dorian1.com/

i tried using hashrouter instead of browserrouter, adding "homepage" in my package.json,

my app.js is :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import './styles/App.css'
import Footer from './footer/Footer'
import Header from './header/Header'
import Search from './search/Search'
import Alert from './alert/Alert'
// PAGES
import News from './pages/news/News'
import Opinion from './pages/opinion/Opinion'
import Sport from './pages/sport/Sport'
import Culture from './pages/culture/Culture'
import Lifestyle from './pages/lifestyle/Lifestyle'
import SearchResults from './pages/searchResults/SearchResults'
import SingleArticle from './pages/SingleArticle/SingleArticle'

function App() {

  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null)

  return (
      <Router>
      <Header />
      <Alert alert={alert}/>
      <Search setAlert={setAlert}/>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={News}/>
      <Route path='/News' component={News}/>
      <Route path='/Opinion' component={Opinion}/>
      <Route path='/Sport' component={Sport}/>
      <Route path='/Culture' component={Culture}/>                           
      <Route path='/Lifestyle' component={Lifestyle}/>
      <Route path='/SearchResults' component={SearchResults}/>
      <Route path='/SingleArticle' component={SingleArticle}/>
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the console on edge says :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
    at redux.js:621
    at f (redux.js:154)
    at Module.454 (store.js:11)
    at a ((index):1)
    at t ((index):1)
    at Array.r [as push] ((index):1)
    at main.a2301ff4.chunk.js:1
```

my index.js is :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

// REDUX
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
// import store from './store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import {store, persistor} from './store'

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: Console shows redux throwing an error.

Comment: i also tried adding basename to my router

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, my store js had thunk middleware imported but never used,

```
const middleware = [thunk];
 export const store = createStore(rootReducer,
     initialState,
     compose(
         applyMiddleware(...middleware),
         window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
     ));
```

i removed the middleware and now its working , makes no sense but hope it helps someone